# inserting row into a tableview from viewdidload

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

i have a uiviewcontroller with a tableview in it. im trying to query through users in my firebase data base but i keep getting this error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'

i looked it up and tried the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods but get the same error on the line that i call endUpdates. any ideas why this is happening?

heres my code:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
definesPresentationContext = true
self.browseTable.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar



    ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.usersArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)

        //insert rows
        //self.browseTable.beginUpdates()

        //where the error occurs
        self.browseTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count - 1,section: 0)], with: .automatic)

        //self.browseTable.endUpdates()


}) { (error) in
    print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")

}
```

Comment: In your `numberOfRowsInSection` method, did you return `self.usersArray.count` or any hardcoded number?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri this is what is in my numberOfRowsInSection method
'if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        
            return filteredUsers.count
        }
        
        return 1'

Comment: If you're going to insert new rows. You should also update the value returned in your `numberOfRows` method to the new number of rows after insertion. By looking at your method and given that you're inserting row at `indexPath.row = self.usersArray.count - 1`, I think this is what causing your crash

Comment: okay i think i got it. thank you! @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri

Comment: is it due to the same reason? If it is, then I will write it as an answer so that it will be helpful for others. Please let me know

Comment: yes it was. @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri

Comment: Thanks. Wrote it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments regarding the problem, the crash is caused due to the value returned in the function `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` not matching the number of rows after inserting rows.

In cases like this where your value returned in `numberOfRowsInSection` function is based on your dataSource object, updating your dataSource object before inserting/deleting rows will resolve the problem.

Feel free to suggest edits :)